# qt binarycreator does not create dmg

Tags: c++, qt, qt-installer

hi i am using the QT binarycreator to create an installer for my QT project.

I have my App.dmg and have 7z it using archivegen.

Now i am trying to make the installer as:

```
~/Qt/QtIFW2.0.1/bin/binarycreator -v --online-only -c config/config.xml -p packages MyAppInstaller.dmg
```

note: packages folder contains the 7z folder inside packages/myapp/data/myapp.7z

but unfortuntaly it only creates MyAppInstaller.app and NOT MyAppInstaller.dmg as mentioned in the documents.

any ideas why?

Answer (score 0):

I'd upgrade to the latest version of the installer framework if you don't have any reason not to.  The new 3.x versions also include the ability to sign dmg packages so they don't show up as unknown application sources.

I had a lot of head scratching with the 2.x versions in QTIFW that the 3.x solved out of the box.

http://blog.qt.io/blog/2018/03/28/qt-installer-framework-3-0-4-released/